# tools/library to do noninvasive logging

Tags: log4net, postsharp, log4postsharp

I am wondering if any tool can help do noninvasive logging for a third party assembly library.  Can log4net/Postsharp do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was a log4netpostsharp library but it hasn't been updated to the latest version of PostSharp so you need to do some custom aspects here most likely (very easy to do though).

An example for logging through trace and postsharp [here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/monitoring#tracing).